# ¿Como evitar que se borre los datos seleccionados y guardarlos en array de objetos o json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Cuando seleeciono los datos , se pasan a otra tabla, y cuando busco varias veces en la tabla principal, se borra la tabla de productos seleccionados,como podria evitarlo y guardarlo en un array de objetos para luego insertarlo en la base de datos .

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="https:https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="https:https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div >
  <table id="mitabla" border="1" class=" display table display table-striped">


  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Check</th>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Articulo</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>Presentacion</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO001</th>
  <th>Mantequilla</th>
  <th>12.5</th>
  <th>50</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO002</th>
  <th>Yogurt</th>
  <th>5.60</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO003</th>
  <th>Gaseosa</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO004</th>
  <th>Pul</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO003</th>
  <th>Gaseosa</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO004</th>
  <th>Pul</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO003</th>
  <th>Gaseosa</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO004</th>
  <th>Pul</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  
  
  
  </tbody>


  </table>
</div>
<table id="tabla2" class=" display table display table-striped">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mitabla').DataTable({
rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
        },
        fixedHeader: true,
        responsive: true,
        autoFill: true,
        paging: true,
        ordering: true,
        searching: true,
        info: true,
       // scrollY:        400, // mantiene en tamaño en el eje y
        deferRender:    true,
        scroller:       true,
"language": {

"sProcessing": "Procesando...",
"sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
"sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
"sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
"sInfo": "Mostrando registros del START al END de un total de TOTAL",
"sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
"sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de MAX registros)",
"sInfoPostFix": "",
"sSearch": "Buscar:",
"sUrl": "",
"sInfoThousands": ",",
"sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
"oPaginate": {
"sFirst": "Primero",
"sLast": "Último",
"sNext": "Siguiente",
"sPrevious": "Anterior"
},
"oAria": {
"sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
"sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
}

}

});


$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  if($(this).is(":checked"))
  {
   // el checkbox esta marcado
   // movemos la columna a la tabla2
   var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#tabla2 tbody");
   
  }else{
   // el checkbox esta desmarcado
   // movemos la columna a la tabla1
   var tr=$(this).parents("tr").appendTo("#mitabla tbody");
  }
   
 });

 

} );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es solo de mover la fila de una tabla a otra, tambien tienes que removerla y agregarla en el objeto `dataTables`.  Algo asi:

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="https:https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="https:https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/js/dataTables.rowReorder.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowreorder/1.2.3/css/rowReorder.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<div >
  <table id="mitabla" border="1" class=" display table display table-striped">


  <thead>
  <tr>
  <th>Check</th>
  <th>Codigo</th>
  <th>Articulo</th>
  <th>Precio</th>
  <th>Cantidad</th>
  <th>Presentacion</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO001</th>
  <th>Mantequilla</th>
  <th>12.5</th>
  <th>50</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO002</th>
  <th>Yogurt</th>
  <th>5.60</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO003</th>
  <th>Gaseosa</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO004</th>
  <th>Pul</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO003</th>
  <th>Gaseosa</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO004</th>
  <th>Pul</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO003</th>
  <th>Gaseosa</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO004</th>
  <th>Pul</th>
  <th>3.50</th>
  <th>40</th>
  <th>En botella</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <td class="check"><input name="" type="checkbox"></td>
  <th>PRO005</th>
  <th>Jamonada</th>
  <th>2.10</th>
  <th>100</th>
  <th>En paquete</th>
  </tr>
  
  
  
  
  </tbody>


  </table>
</div>
<table id="tabla2" class=" display table display table-striped">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#mitabla').DataTable({
rowReorder: {
            selector: 'td:nth-child(2)'
        },
        fixedHeader: true,
        responsive: true,
        autoFill: true,
        paging: true,
        ordering: true,
        searching: true,
        info: true,
       // scrollY:        400, // mantiene en tamaño en el eje y
        deferRender:    true,
        scroller:       true,
"language": {

"sProcessing": "Procesando...",
"sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
"sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
"sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
"sInfo": "Mostrando registros del START al END de un total de TOTAL",
"sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
"sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de MAX registros)",
"sInfoPostFix": "",
"sSearch": "Buscar:",
"sUrl": "",
"sInfoThousands": ",",
"sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
"oPaginate": {
"sFirst": "Primero",
"sLast": "Último",
"sNext": "Siguiente",
"sPrevious": "Anterior"
},
"oAria": {
"sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
"sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
}

}

});


$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    var table = $('#mitabla').DataTable();
  if($(this).is(":checked"))
  {          
            var row = table.row( $(this).parents('tr') );
            var rowNode = row.node();
            row.remove();
     
   var tr=$(rowNode).appendTo("#tabla2 tbody");
   
  }else{
   // el checkbox esta desmarcado
   // movemos la columna a la tabla1
            var tr=$(this).parents("tr").detach();
            table.row.add(tr).draw();
  }
   
 });

 

} );
</script>
```

Comment: hola @alanfcm ,esta bien lo que hiciste,pero adicional a eso quiero que me guarde en un array  de objetos  o json ,los items seleccionados, y que me enprima con console log, como seria?.